# Upvoting and Downvoting Reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In a question on Meta Stack Exchange, I found out that a user loses 1 reputation when downvoting an answer. This is a feature introduced to the Stack Exchange communities so that downvoting is discouraged. It would be rather more convenient to ignore the answer or ask the user who answered to produce a better explanation other than downvote.

What about upvoting? We usually do not gain any reputation when upvoting good questions. It is true that there are badges for this, but in my opinion, this is not enough to encourage a positive attitude of upvoting good answers. How about increasing reputation on answers by 1 when upvoting, the same as losing 1 reputation when downvoting?

Comment: At the moment there is an occasional reminder "questions need love too; please consider upvoting the question as well as the answer"

Comment: Also, this would just lead to people upvoting everything just to get points. Definitely not wanted.

Comment: It's not enough to reward good contributions, even though it costs you nothing. You need a reward for clicking an "up" arrow?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp +1, now where's my rep?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

We want people to up-vote posts because they are good posts, not because you can earn reputation.

It is a *monumentally bad idea* to award reputation to up-voting as that would incentivise  entirely the wrong behaviour; namely the up voting of everything in sight. Say goodbye to quality control!

You should only ever *earn* reputation; through the actions of others. That way reputation reflects community trust. You get reputation when people vote on your posts, when reviewers accept your suggested edit, when your answer is marked as accepted, or you received a great answer so you can mark it as accepted.

Because reputation is only ever earned, making something cost you reputation is a very effective method to make users think about the action. We want you to be  sure when down-voting a post. Reputation gain and loss is a finely tuned instrument here, you are being manipulated to Do The Right Thing as much as possible; post quality content, and help maintain that quality.

You are free to ignore any bad answer or question you come across, but take into account that by down voting such posts, you are helping separate the chaff from the wheat on this site. If you know an answer to be wrong or to be unhelpful in other ways, please *do* down vote it. A down vote is a powerful signal to the author that something about their post might need improving.

Comment: Just think of how much rep [user998692](http://stackoverflow.com/users/998692/user998692) would have if up votes gave +1 rep to the person casting the vote.

Comment: @MichaelT Well, about 24 882, give or take any caching delays. That is one extremely positive user. Or everyone's sockpuppet.

Answer (score 4):

You will be upvoting each and every post if your suggested idea of " **increasing reputation on answers by 1 when upvoting** " is implemented. Rather than this, it feels good when you upvote some answer considering the correctness, effort, logics and other aspects of the answer. I myself while surfing on StackOverflow,upvote all the answers that scroll in front of me and helped me to gain something, increasing my knowledge.

---

If someone who wish to learn and respect the knowledge of the answerer; will humbly feel no hesitation while upvoting some answers