# Give downvotes more/less weight depending on the voter's reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As you know, some people probably doesn't understand because of the poor writing for a question and then cast a downvote. What if the people who have a high reputation can vote down more than those who do not have a high reputation or putting value for downvote depend on the reputation?

Some users don't have experience like most of the users here. Moreover, they can't explain the question as some of you do or maybe they are not good in English. By voting down it prevents them from getting benefit from Stack Overflow.

Comment: I understand this question, and that's why I downvote it.

Comment: @Braiam thanks so much for your understanding.

Comment: Just downvotes? I wonder why you don't care about upvotes... But anyway, I don't like this idea and  I don't see a real benefit of it

Comment: @AlonEitan voting up means that he got a good answer for his problem.

Comment: If you have a proposal you need to explain what the problem is you're trying to address and why your suggestion would fix it.

Comment: @i_th Not necessarily - It can also mean that a user answering the question will upvote the question in the hope that the OP will also upvote their answer, or if it's simply a good question that shows that the OP really tried to address the issue themselves before asking, or a question about a common issue, if the voter is in a good/bad mood, and probably other reasons

Comment: @RobertLongson sometimes I read a good question and maybe good answers with downvote.

Comment: and why do you think weighted voting would fix that issue?

Comment: @i_th _I read a good question and maybe good answers with downvote_ One possible reason is that the OP originally posted a question without providing and code or the question lacks enough  relevant details, this usually end with lot's of downvote. But then the OP edit the question and adding the missing details which makes it a good question. But by that time it's too late and the downvotes are there to stay, with the hope that other users might average the negative votes with their upvotes

Comment: *"As you know some people probably doesn't understand the question and then put downvote."* ... I don't know whether that's the case at all. It's an assumption you make, which would require proof. And perhaps first of all a step back from you to objectively evaluate your question and really check whether or not it's as good and clear as you think it is.

Comment: So… users with a low reputation would be able to vote -1, and users with a high reputation would be able to vote -10? How in the world does that fix the problem of users downvoting a question they supposedly don't understand?!

Comment: @deceze  three of the users with a low reputation count as one with high  reputation or put number if they reach 1000 or more count as vote -1

Comment: Can we try and keep the voting system simple, please? Votes aren't the problem, **bad content is.**

Comment: @deceze Those who start at StackOverflow can't get the whole benefit from it because of the downvote.

Comment: So that's the real issue you're driving at… can you provide a sample of a post which was downvoted because low-rep users didn't properly understand it, but which was otherwise perfectly in line with SO's quality standards?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276971/upvoting-and-downvoting-reputation?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878329/how-can-i-read-one-line-from-more-than-one-files-very-quickly-c-sharp
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272256/disable-downvoting-for-users-with-reputation-less-than-50?rq=1

Comment: That's not exactly a question I'd uphold as a good example of being misunderstood. It *isn't* a great question that deserves particularly high visibility in the system.

Comment: "Make this code dump faster" isn't a very good question on StackOverflow and it would take the kind of answer you see on a good [codereview.se] question to address all the issues. Instead, you should have asked about what part of that you think is the performance issue and ways on which to improve that.

Comment: Two of the questions you linked to are **meta** questions. Down votes on meta don't affect your reputation at all.

Comment: The close reason on your question wasn't "unclear" it was "too broad" and all of the users who voted to close it have over 15K. Most of the people who commented or answered had 1K (which isn't "high" but they aren't new either). I don't understand why you think the problem is with low rep users who didn't understand the question.

Comment: The problem is not that I got the downvote. We are here to learn. Some users don't have an experience like most of the user here.Moreover, they can't explain the question as some of you do or maybe they are not good in English. By voting down it prevents them from getting benefit from StackOverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are Stack Overflow users more passionate about Stack Overflow than helping people?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315018/why-are-stack-overflow-users-more-passionate-about-stack-overflow-than-helping-p)

Comment: @bart It doesn't seem like an unreasonable assumption to me. The majority of the questions that I downvote, it's because the question makes very little sense and I couldn't understand it. Naturally there are other reasons why someone might downvote a question, but I don't think it's very far-fetched to assume that "unclear" is one of them—it's even in the downvote tooltip. Which brings me to the question for i_th: why is this bad? Don't you agree that a question that is unclear to experts *should* be downvoted? Speaking of unclear, it's unclear to me what you're actually proposing we change.

Comment: @CodyGray, I fear the OP by "doesn't understand the question" means "the question is perfectly clear, but the user doesn't have the capacity to understand it", rather than that the question is hard to understand. But maybe that's my Meta bias.

Comment: The sad part about this is it would likely negatively affect those who want this far more than they think.

Answer (score 32):

> some people probably doesn't understand the question and then put downvote

The number of times this *non sequitur* is repeated is mind-boggling. It's especially claimed by frustrated people who had their question downvoted or closed and can't understand why.

In comments, you were asked for an example. In response you linked to a question of yours, [How to read the same line from multiple files very quickly C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878329/how-can-i-read-one-line-from-more-than-one-files-very-quickly-c-sharp):

> When all files is bigger than 60 Mb ,it works very slowly.
>
> ```
>      int count1 = File.ReadLines(sharesList.Items[0].ToString()).Count();
>
>            //The sharesList contains all files
>
>             for (int m = 0; m < count1; m++)
>                {          
>                foreach (String s in sharesList.Items)
>                 {
>                     if (File.Exists(s))
>                     {
>                         string shar1 = File.ReadAllLines(s).Skip(m).Take(1).First();
>
>                         if (shar1 != null && shar1 != "")
>                         {
>                             sharesL.Add(shar1);
>
>                         }
>
>
>                     }
>                   }
>                }
> ```
>
> Could anyone tell me how to make it very fast? Thanks in Advance

The reputation of the five people who close-voted that question as "too broad" is at least 15,000. I can only assume the same for the seven downvoters, and on the contrary, the single person who upvoted it probably felt bad for you or found it cool that you work with 60MB files.

Instead of providing a minimal example, you dump a bunch of code with obfuscated variable names that does some nasty things to files, and expect us to reverse engineer what it does, identify hotspots, find better ways to let it do exactly the same but more efficient, and post that as an answer. Those aren't the kinds of questions—or answers—Stack Overflow is looking for, because they won't be helpful to future users.

To understand why your question gets downvoted or closed, you really need to take a step back, read the question in the preview screen as if you were someone who was *not* you, who does *not* understand what you're trying to do, and evaluate whether it actually makes sense and is a good question. This is the crucial step that many people miss.

What you're suggesting here (*"make downvotes weigh heavier for users with higher reputation"*) would *not* have changed the way your question was treated on the site, and more importantly, it wouldn't have improved the actual quality of your question—which is really the ultimate goal.

Comment: tl;DR: people downvoted that question because doesn't show research effort; it's unclear or not useful.

Comment: @CodeCaster I modified the question. Could you please give me the answer?

Answer (score 6):

> As you know some people probably doesn't understand the question and then put downvote. What if the people who have a high reputation can vote down more than those who do not have a high reputation

Surely this would make things worse as if I were willing to downvote something once, more often than not I wouldn't be afraid to downvote again - resulting in your question being downvoted a lot more heavily.

---

But this isn't what you were really asking about.

The large majority of people don't downvote unless it meets one of the criteria for a downvote which you can hover over a downvote button to reveal

- Does not show any research effort
- It is unclear
- It is not useful

So don't be surprised if your question gets downvoted if it can be categorised into one of these.

Now [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878329/how-can-i-read-one-line-from-more-than-one-files-very-quickly-c-sharp) that presumably prompted this question was unclear because it wasn't clear what part of that code dump was causing you performance issues, and it showed some level of lack of research since it doesn't appear that you ever tried to diagnose which line of that wasn't running as fast as you'd hoped.

So don't blame the voters, its **your responsibility** to ensure that your question is of an adequate quality.